# error: call of overloaded ‘max(int, int)’ is ambiguous

Tags: c++, stl

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

template<typename T>
T max(T lhs, T rhs)
{
  return lhs < rhs ? rhs : lhs;
}
template<>
int max<int>(int lhs, int rhs)
{
  return lhs < rhs ? rhs : lhs;
}

int main()
{
  cout << max<int>(4, 5) << endl;

}

~/Documents/C++/boost $ g++ -o testSTL testSTL.cpp -Wall
testSTL.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
testSTL.cpp:18:24: error: call of overloaded ‘max(int, int)’ is ambiguous
testSTL.cpp:11:5: note: candidates are: T max(T, T) [with T = int]
/usr/include/c++/4.5/bits/stl_algobase.h:209:5: note:                 const _Tp& std::max(const _Tp&, const _Tp&) [with _Tp = int]
```

How do I correct this error?

Comment: Remove the `using namespace std;`

Comment: @VJovic: That's no excuse. At the same time the rest of the English used was learned, the proper way to ask a question could have been. I don't understand where anyone, native English speaker or not, would get the idea that "how to correct this error" is magically a valid question construct.

Comment: @RichardJ.RossIII: Not everybody on this site is a native english speaker and it can be difficult to sense the real meaning of an expression. At least the final goal is reached: you understood what he asked. :)

Comment: I'd hazard a guess English isn't their first language - I wish I was that good at a foreign language, so I can't complain :p

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit: As a native french speaker, "How to correct this error" is a literal translation of the perfectly valid "Comment corriger cette erreur ?". Now the OP seems to live in Chicago so I'm not sure my point holds.

Comment: @ereOn I could understand that, but he lives in Chicago, IL according to his profile.

Comment: @ereOn: You don't need to be a native English speaker to know that what may be valid construct in one language isn't automatically the same, when literally translated word-for-word, in another! On the other hand, English _does_ have a rather backwards interrogative construction, in that you can't just shove a `?` at the end of the sentence like in other languages (such as French) but instead you have to inject an otherwise-redundant conjugation of "to do".

Comment: @RichardJ.RossIII: I went to his profile as well and that bugged me too. Still, it could be a foreigner living in Chicago (I heard it was a nice city to live in). Anyway, does it really matter ?

Comment: @ereOn: It does, to some. It's called OCD.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit: I wasn't trying to find an excuse, merely an explanation ;)

Comment: @ereOn: Fair enough. Meanwhile, I love the way the French say "foreigner", and now I've been able to virtually "hear" it thanks to your comment. Lights up my day, so thanks! :D

Comment: @ereOn: foh reeeee nuh hahaha

Answer (score 21, accepted):

It's all because of your `using namespace std;`. Remove that line.
By that using-directive, you bring `std::max` (which must be somehow included via iostream) into the global scope. Therefore the compiler doesn't know which `max` to call - `::max` or `std::max`.

I hope this example will be a good scarecrow for those who think that using directives come at no cost. Weird errors are one side effect.

Comment: It's worth noting ADL side-effects of not using them though. :-D Ex: no one writes std::cout.operator<<("hello world!").operator<<(std::endl); even though that is required for defined behavior without using declarations/directives, as ADL is not standardized across compilers. Sutter has a whole section on this on why using directives should be encouraged in C++ Coding Standards because of the undefined behaviors that result from inadvertently depending on ADL.

Comment: @stinky472: As opposed to what? `std::cout << "hello world!" << std::endl;`? How does that rely on ADL?

Comment: @stinky472: ADL is standard. Compilers not supporting it should be thrown away.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit: It does, because `operator <<` is not a member function. It's a freestanding function in std namespace. In order *not* to rely on ADL, you'd have to write : `std::operator << (std::cout, "Hello world")`

Comment: @stinky472: Sutter has lots of sections in lots of books about why not do this or that, because while it is standard, msvc doesnt work properly with it. This is all driven by FUD and the pressure should be put on the compiler people to fix their stuff instead of programmers to use fugly workarounds. ADL works fine in the major open source compilers btw.

Comment: @Armen: Ah yes, I see. Is it really UB to use ADL? Something tells me "no".

Comment: The rules of ADL are apparently not from my understanding. All reasonable compilers provide ADL just to support the hello world example, but 'how' is where we get into undefined territory. I can't help but think using directives are beneficial though as Sutter argues.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit: Of course not. ADL was invented primarily because of the issues with operators, so it's perfectly OK to rely on ADL.

Comment: Though at the same time I like your rationality of simply increasing pressure on compiler vendors to properly support ADL in a uniform and predictable way.

Comment: @stinky472: ADL rules are well-defined in the C++ standard and they are far less complicated than rules of, say, overload resolution or template point of intantiation. I think *not* relying on ADL is a bad practice, rather than the reverse

Comment: Oh you're right, I had to revisit the original source material I remembered this from, but it seems that only some implementations fail to adhere to ADL standards, so essentially trying to avoid ADL would be a workaround for broken compilers as you said. Unfortunately I've had the unpleasant experience of having to work with this broken down compilers including fixing issues porting code (which is where I first discovered what ADL was). Perhaps it is not much of an issue anymore.

Comment: What then, are your thoughts on using declarations as opposed to using directives? Do you prefer those or fully qualified names?

Comment: @stinky472: I mostly prefer qualified names. Further, if the namespace name is too long, one can use a namespace alias (e.g. `using namespace bl = boost::lambda;`. In some cases, I can afford writing a using directive, but only in function scope and ***NEVER*** in a header file. The thing is that if you're sufficiently good at C++, you can "risk" using directives if you're sure they are benign. But I think beginners should be taught to use qualified names...

Comment: @stinky472:  I'm not following.  Could you give me an example where a conforming implementation of ADL would fail to translate `std::cout << "hello world!" << std::endl;` and would translate `std::cout.operator<<("hello world!").operator<<(std::endl);`?  Sutter's Exceptional C++, items 31-34, doesn't claim that there's any difference between the two.  Nor do I see any chance for ADL to screw things up, since `char *` isn't a class, unlike, say, `mystring a("hello, world!"); std::cout << a << std::endl;`, which can get messed up.  Nor do I see what `using namespace std;` has to do with this ADL

Comment: @David of course not. If a compiler failed to compile such a simpistic example, its implementation of ADL would be hopelessly bad. The example Sutter gives is this: namespace N {struct X {};   template<typename T> int* operator+( T , unsigned ) {/* do something */}} int main() {std::vector<N::X> v(5);v[0];}

Comment: This is from C++ Coding Standards and, to sum Sutter's perspective, "Bottom line: You shouldn't have to know this stuff.[...] In short: You can and should use namespace using declarations and directives liberally in your implementation files after #include directives and feel good about it. Despite repeated assertions to the contrary, namespace using declarations and directives are not evil and they do not defeat the purpose of namespaces. Rather, they are what make namespaces usable."

Comment: Not to overly defend Sutter's stance though as I'd agree with Armen that this is really more of an issue with compilers failing to implement ADL correctly and it makes more sense to put pressure on compilers to conform than to seek workarounds which avoid ADL implementation problems.

Answer (score 5):

I guess the compiler can't work out whether to use std::max or your max, because you've got a using namespace std; and both your max and the std::max fit the bill

Answer (score 4):

You're colliding with `std::max()`. Rename it to something else like `mymax` and it will work.

Comment: Even better to not define it in `std` namespace, like Armen mentioned.

Comment: The OP never defined it in `std` namespace. I advised against bringing all the names of `std` namespace into the global scope

Comment: The whole point of putting the standard library in std namespace is so you can define your own `max` function in some other namespace (or globally), or in general, don't have to constantly think which names are used in the standard (or any other) library. What's the point of namespaces in the first place, if you don't employ them to resolve naming collisions and keep doing with prefixes instead?!

Answer (score 4):

You have both your `max` and `std::max`. The compiler doesn't know which one you intended to call.

You can tell it by calling `::max(4,5)` or `std::max(4,5)`, or - even better - not have `using namespace std` in the file.

Answer (score 3):

That's because there's already std::max template function defined.
Remove the 'using namespace std' and add 'std::' where needed., or use '::max'.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that there is already a function named 'max' defined by std. To fix this, rename your function to something else, like this:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

template<typename T>
T mymax(T lhs, T rhs)
{
    return lhs < rhs ? rhs : lhs;
}
template<>
int mymax<int>(int lhs, int rhs)
{
    return lhs < rhs ? rhs : lhs;
}

int main()
{
    cout << mymax<int>(4, 5) << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: And stop using `using namespace std`