# C++ Template compilation error

Tags: c++, templates

I am new to templates and I am trying to test this out after reading up on how to do templates, but I'm getting a compilation error and my code looks the exact same as the example I took from. I create a function and I have a template, but when I compile it I get the following error:

> 15 20  C:\Users\Fire\Desktop\test.cpp  [Error] call of overloaded 'max(int, int)' is ambiguous
>
> 15 20  C:\Users\Fire\Desktop\test.cpp  [Note] candidates are:
>
> 7  3   C:\Users\Fire\Desktop\test.cpp  [Note] T max(T, T) [with T = int]

The code is as follows:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

template<typename T>
T max(T a, T b){
    return (a > b)? a: b;
}    

int main(){
    cout << max<int>(10, 40);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Never say `using namespace std;`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [error: call of overloaded ‘max(int, int)’ is ambiguous](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9097509/error-call-of-overloaded-maxint-int-is-ambiguous)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

std::max is a function defined in C++. Call your function myMax or something like that and it should work

Answer (score 4):

`std::max` is part of the `std` namespace. You are doing `using namespace std` and resolving all functions without the `std` qualifier. This means you have 2 versions of `max` in your code. Yours and `namespace std`. To solve this, [never do `using namespace std`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-bad-practice).

Comment: Thank you I had no idea!

Comment: @Shinji-san If this answered your question please mark it as the correct answer.